# Using Dotfuscator with .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotfuscator

Googling showed me no results on how to use Dotfuscator to obfuscate .DLLs targeting .NET Core 1.0. Should I just use ordinary Dotfuscator version and no special settings for that? Will the resulting obfuscated .dll still be fully compatible with .NET Core?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Not yet. It may take a while to convert my lib to .net core. So I can't first do the conversion and then find out that I cannot use Dotfuscator. If Dotfuscator is not an option, I'd better know this in the first place and instead of adding support of .net core consider adding other features. Making a simple test lib and dotfuscating it will not prove much because it may work on simple things but not not on complex multi-megabyte codebase.

Comment: Their latest version is still not working with .NET Core, mscorlib dependency appears in the obfuscated dll. No types from this dll can be consumed then.

Comment: OK, if I disassemble the obfuscated dll into IL, replace mscorlib references with System.Runtime and build it from IL again, it seems to work. Now will need to automate this but it should be easy.

Comment: Checks are not supported by CE as per today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Dotfuscator is a commercial product, you can contact their support and ask about .NET Core / netstandard compatibility. If dotfuscator was able to obfuscate old PCL assemblies, it should work for .NET Core as well.

Recently I've tested open-source Obfuscar with my assembly that targets netstandard1.5, and I was able to use the dll in .NET Core project after obfuscation.

Comment: This is not an answer, only an opinion. Actually Checks are not supported for .NET Core as  per today's date.